# TCP Listener on GAE Flex possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

With most of the SO q&a on this topic outdated, and GCP in the middle of reshuffling documentation, Its very hard to find info on whether its possible to open a TCP (low level using node net ) server on an app engine flex app to the external world (iot sensor application will pipe messages to node server).